Metric AWS doesn't graph while SEARCH does
I've the following metric that doesn't graph anything while the SEARCH function with the same parameters does, how can I debug this?
Metric:

Search query: SEARCH('Namespace="CWAgent" InstanceId="i-0101620939177e6e4" MetricName="mem_used_percent"', 'Average', 300)

